# Display Thumnail URI in image icon from server

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, imageurl

I want to display thumbnail image as image icon in ListView.
I am using array list that contains all thumbnail images path, these path will be accessed from the server.
My arraylist as ahown below.

```
mylist=['a1','a2','/playback/2012/a1.jpg','b1','b2','/playback/2012/000_b1.jpg', .....]
```

In this nearly 15 paths are there.. Now i want to display these images in listview.

> 'a1' is videoName 'a2' is categoryName and one more is path.

These path will be accessed from server only.. I think, we can't store it in drawable.
These are always changing.
How to solve it?

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ImageView` in the layout for `ListView` items and load images as described here:

[How to load an ImageView by URL in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471935/how-to-load-an-imageview-by-url-in-android)

and optionally here:

[Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview)